# Matrix indexed by another matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have the following matrices:

```
A=zeros(2,4);
D=[ 1 2;
    3 4;
    5 6;
    7 8];

v=rand(1,8);
```

For example:

```
v= [0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469]
```

Now when I run `A(D)=v`,  `A` becomes:

```
A=[0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134;
   0.6324    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469]
```

When I change `D` entries to another values, I get different configurations of `A`, for example, if I put:

```
D=[ 8 7;
    6 5;
    4 3;
    2 1];
```

then `A` becomes:

```
A=[0.5469    0.2785    0.0975    0.6324;
   0.9134    0.1270    0.9058    0.8147]
```

Does any one know what this kind of indexing is?

Comment: It's linear indexing: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to make it clearer lets redefine your `v` as

```
v = 10:10:80
```

(i.e. `v = [10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80];`)

Now when

```
 D=[8 7;
    6 5; 
    4 3; 
    2 1];
```

then

```
A(D)=v

    A =

    80    70    60    50
    40    30    20    10
```

Lets look at how this works. So firstly when you index `A` by `D`, `D` gets flattened so `A(D) = v` is the same as `A(D(:)) = v` (test it!) and

```
D(:)

ans =

     8
     6
     4
     2
     7
     5
     3
     1
```

So for breaking it down element by element we're going `A(D(1)) = v(1)` which after substituting for `D(1)` and `v(1)` is `A(8) = 10`, hence the last element is 10. Lets look a few elements further. `A(D(4)) = v(4)` become `A(2) = 40`. but which element is `A(2)`? Well linear indexing counts down the rows first (column major ordering) i.e.

```
A(1) == A(1,1)
A(2) == A(2,1)
A(3) == A(1,2)
A(4) == A(2,2)
A(5) == A(1,3)
A(6) == A(2,3)
etc...
```

So `A(2)` is in the `(2,1)` position etc...